# How to access an odbc database with Java?

Tags: java, ms-access, odbc

Actually I am working on a Java application that requires an ODBC.
I created the database ms Access and the class connection is working but when I try to add a table in the database an exception appears:

```
java.sql.SQLException: [Microsoft][Pilote ODBC Microsoft Access] Impossible de modifier la structure de la table ??personne??. La base de donn?es est en lecture seule.
    at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbc.createSQLException(JdbcOdbc.java:6956)
    at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbc.standardError(JdbcOdbc.java:7113)
    at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbc.SQLExecDirect(JdbcOdbc.java:3109)
    at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcStatement.execute(JdbcOdbcStatement.java:337)
    at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcStatement.executeQuery(JdbcOdbcStatement.java:252)
    at inventaire.NewClass1.main(NewClass1.java:28)
```

The database is on mode read only.

How can I set the database read and write?

Comment: More detail would be useful, like what driver you are using and what the connection string looks like. However, http://www.planet-source-code.com/vb/scripts/ShowCode.asp?txtCodeId=2691&lngWId=2 has examples including create table.

Comment: It would be easier to figure out what you have done wrong if you share the code you used to connect to the database.
Use [this](http://www.mundayweb.com/progs/jdbc-odbc-tut.php) link to troubleshoot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ODBC-JDBC bridge should be avoided when possible.

Remember, while setting the dsn, set the readonly to 0.

Heres an example on how to work with JDBC-ODBC with MS Access (its not complete)

http://www.mundayweb.com/progs/jdbc-odbc-tut.php

The driver list:

http://devapp.sun.com/product/jdbc/drivers/search_results.jsp?jdbc_version=0&vendor_name=&cert_mode=and&jdbc_driver_type_mode=and&dbms=6&dbms_mode=and&features_mode=and&results_per_page=20&submit=Search

As jere indicated, some drivers need to be explicitly defined & in this case could be ReadOnly=False, Some drivers need a password to edit the database.

regards

Comment: I did all of that and i still got an exception :

Answer (score 1):

try adding `"ReadOnly=False;"` to your connection string. are you sure you have write access to the database file? also check in the advanced options in the odbc dsn if ReadOnly is set to 0.

Answer (score 1):

In order to connect from your java application to the access database you should use the native odbc bridge. Go to your control panel -> Administrative Tools-> ODBC Data Sources and then add your access file there

Comment: I did all of that and i still got the same exception : the dababase is in mode read only.

Answer (score 1):

Try looking in the "Advanced" configuration options of you Access ODBC data source.

There you should find a "ReadOnly" option...

Experimenting with this option using Microsoft odbctest gives -

```
With: ReadOnly = 1

SQLExecDirect:
    In: hstmt = 0x00613250, 
        szSqlStr = "create table test1 (c1 integer)", cbSqlStr = -3
    Return: SQL_ERROR=-1
    stmt:   szSqlState = "42000", *pfNativeError = -1809, *pcbErrorMsg = 116, *ColumnNumber = -2, *RowNumber = -2
    MessageText = "[Microsoft][ODBC Microsoft Access Driver] Cannot modify the design of table 'test1'.  It is in a read-only database."
```

which is the same error you are getting...

```
With: ReadOnly = 0

SQLExecDirect:
    In: hstmt = 0x00613288, 
        szSqlStr = "create table test1 (c1 integer)", cbSqlStr = -3
    Return: SQL_SUCCESS=0
```

The SQL_SUCCESS indicates the DDL statement was successful...